# CoreData issue: -[NSManagedObject setValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios, nsmanagedobject

I just started with CoreData yesterday, and I'm going crazy :( I created a project that uses CoreData (ticked the box -use CoreData). Created the entities, and then created the NSManagedObject classes for all the entities (I suppose they create the 'setter' and 'getter' methods for the entities).

Now, I #imported all these classes in my AppDeletegate and wrote this in my applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

(Subscriptions is one of the Entities in the application)

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
 Subscriptions *sbs = (Subscriptions *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Subscriptions" inManagedObjectContext:context];
 [sbs setTitle:@"OK"];
 [sbs setType:@"Tag"];
 [sbs setCode:@"cars"];

 NSError *error = nil;
 if (![context save:&error]) {
  NSLog(@"Couldn't create the subscription");
 }
```

When I run this, I get this error

> [NSManagedObject setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6160550

I have no idea why this is happening. Please Help!!!
Thanks in advance to everyone!

**Adding the header of Subscriptions**

Subscriptions.h

> @interface Subscriptions :  NSManagedObject { 
>   }
>   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Type;
>   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * Read;
>   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Title;
>   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Code;
>   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * New;
>   @end

I didn't change anything. It's just as Xcode created it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having a similar problem.  Any message I send to my NSManagedObject subclass says "unrecognized selector".

Comment: @bdmontz It's been a while, I don't really remember how I fixed it. Sorry.

Comment: @bdmontz (and anyone else stumbling across this problem). Check the answer from b123400. Helped me. I had forgotten about changing the class name in the data model in a refactoring of the entity class name.

Answer (score 33):

Just to remind that, don't use capitalized variable name, it might affects the getters and setters not working properly.

If you generated your NSManagedObject subclasses from the data model, everything should goes fine, although it is @dynamic, setters are be implemented by coredata, and because they are already implemented, you should not change it to synthesize.
At least for me, coredata returns empty object after I change @dynamic to @synthesize.

And don't forget to set the class name in the data model:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It was that last thing about class name in the model that bit me.

Comment: Dude you are life saver. awesome! class name took my two hours.

Comment: I am having this problem, but doing by data model provided by Xcode, all of the things you said are correctly set. My problem lies someplace else.

Answer (score 12):

I was getting this, and did a Clean on the project and it fixed it.

Comment: I met the same problem and clean the project fix it!

Answer (score 4):

I added an attirbute to a Core Data entity, and instead of re-creating the NSManagedObjectSubclass, *I tried to get fancy and manually add the @property and @dynamic to the existing subclass.*

*That didn't work*, so I went and re-created the subclass through XCode, which is when I started getting this error ("unrecognized selector sent to instance" when setting a value for the attribute).

So I **created a new version of the Core Data Model via XCode**, then cleaned, deleted derived data, and **then re-created the NSManagedObject subclass**. That worked.

It was probably creating a new data model and the new subclass based on that, so I probably didn't need to clean or delete derived data...but it didn't hurt, either!

Comment: I had a similar issue that I was able to fix just by changing the current model version, and then changing it back. I also did a clean, though that by itself didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Two possible problems

Do you have corresponding @dynamic block in the .m file for these properties and

Dont use Capitalised properties, coding conventions are that properties are lowercase for the first letter at least so that when the compiler synthesises the methods.

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;` in .h

and

`@dynamic type;` in .m

becomes something like

```
-(void)setType:(NSString *)atype
{
....
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"type"];
[self setPrimitiveValue:atype forKey:@"type"];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"type"];
} 

-(NSString *)type
{
return [self primitiveValueForKey:@"type"];
}
```

in the background. Though you cant see that code ever.

Case conventions are up to you but Camel Caps is nominally normal with Cocoa. But its much like an object such as `Big Furry Cat` becomes `bigFurryCat`. Follow the style in the apple examples.

**EDIT** - change @synthesize to @dynamic

Comment: @Graham - Just double checked, you have to synthesize if you are going to use your MO properties as Obj-C 2.0 properties. Please explain.

Comment: if you synthesize properties you get ivar-backed properties, which you don't want with NSManagedObject subclasses. You want to allow NSManagedObject to lazily provide the accessors using the entity description.

Comment: For NSManagedObject I'd use @dynamic instead of @synthesized.

Comment: Probably better , but the pre-processor seems to get it right anyway as I checked with this answer that the MOC was getting updated if you use @synthesize.

Answer (score 2):

I found that by having relations to entities I had to make sure some of my relations would be to-many, I took a screenshot so you can see what I mean, a to-many relation is indicated by the double ended arrow

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like Title attribute may not be set to string. Have you check that?

Usually, unrecognized selector sent to instance is a runtime error cause by sending a message to an object that the object doesn't know how to handle.

```
Subscriptions *sbs = (Subscriptions *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Subscriptions" inManagedObjectContext:context];
sbs.Title = @"OK";
```

Hope that help

[I made simple project here.](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B-q_cL9Fu4OxOGMyMjlmMmUtZDhkZi00YjZmLTkzZGUtMjlkNmQ5ODRiMzli&authkey=CJ6EyecH&hl=en)

Comment: I checked, it is set to NSString :-(
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Title;

Comment: I meant in the Entity. In the Data Model.

Comment: That one is also a string. The class is created based on the Entity, so I guess these kind of errors shouldn't be happening.

Comment: I got it. Subscriptions *sbs = (Subscriptions *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Subscriptions" inManagedObjectContext:context];
 sbs.Title = @"OK";

Comment: I tried that one too, but it gives me pretty much the same error. :(

Comment: @Suwitcha Sugthana: If the dot syntax works, there is absolutely no reason the `setTitle:` syntax should not work.

Comment: It works on mine. I made a simple project here. Try to compare.   http://tinyurl.com/379whtm

Comment: I tried using this method: [sbs setValue:@"OK" forKey:@"Title"]; but I get this other error.                
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSManagedObject 0x614ea00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: the entity Subscriptions is not key value coding-compliant for the key "Title".'
Now I just feel dumber :(

Comment: @Suwitcha Sugthana - It works, and my code is pretty much same as yours. I'll create another project. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found a not-so-elegant solution. It seems that

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"myEntity" inManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext];
```

creates an old version of `myEntity` that does not have the attributes of the most up-to-date version. So I changed the name of `myEntity` in the old version of the model to `myEntityOld` and I did not get the error any more.

I suspect that there is an elegant way to do the same thing in XCode by setting a property of `NSManagedObject` or `NSEntityDescription`.

Answer (score 0):

take the following steps

1) created a new version of the Core Data Model via Xcode.

2) Fix the relationship (added a new relationship between the two.
)

[Creating Managed Object Relationships](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html)

3) re-created the NSManagedObject subclass